# NSOpenPanel crashes under Mountain Lion

Tags: xcode4, osx-mountain-lion, nsopenpanel

In several of my projects I am using the following code:

```
NSOpenPanel * ProfilOpenPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[ProfilOpenPanel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[ProfilOpenPanel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[ProfilOpenPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
[ProfilOpenPanel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"txt"]];
int antwort=[ProfilOpenPanel runModal];
```

Since upgrading to 10.8 and Xcode4.5, this code doesn’t work any more.
The panel opens, but then the app crashes with a message in the Debug Navigator as:
    quicklook.pluginload(serial)
    1 Thread
    Thread 5
    14 _pthread_wqthread

In the console, a couple of warnings appear:
    WindowServer: CGXDeferSurfaces: Invalid source window 19938
and another warning:
    28.September.12 12:10:40.001 Xcode[78227]: [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in      /SourceCache/IDEKit/IDEKit-1854/Framework/Classes/Editor/IDEEditorContext.m:617
    Details: Lost history for x-xcode-disassembly://stack_frame?   processID=31774&threadID=12&frameID=0
    Object:
    Method: -_greatestDocumentAncestorWasForgotten
    Thread: {name = (null), num = 1}
    Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.

Comment: Can you please post the complete stacktrace, with symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabling my exception breakpoint in xcode worked for me. Or try just disabling all breakpoints.

Source: answer to the same poster on a blog at http://cyborgdino.com/2012/02/nsopenpanel-displaying-a-file-open-dialog-in-os-x-10-7/#comment-702